# Filter list of tuples to output list using a conditional

Tags: function, haskell, filter, functional-programming, tuples

I want to use the standard Prelude in Haskell (no recursion, no list comprehension) to filter a list of tuples and then output a list of integers. It should check a list of 3-tuples that contain integers, e.g.,

```
[(1,2,3), (2,3,7), (4,5,20)]
```

and see if the sum of element #1 and #2 equals element #3. If it does, put element #3 in the list and then output the list. This is the output that I am looking for:

```
>sumOfElements [(1,2,3), (2,3,7), (4,5,9)]
[3,9]
```

This is what I have tried:

```
sumsOfElements :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> [Int]
sumsOfElements list = filter (\(a,b,c) -> a+b==c) list
```

This kind of works but it outputs a list of tuples that meets the conditional.

```
>sumOfElements [(1,2,3), (2,3,7), (4,5,9)]
[(1,2,3), (4,5,9)]
```

I'm not sure how to take `c` from the tuple and append that element to a new list for the output.

Answer (score 9):

Think about this as a pipeline: first find the right elements, then transform them into the shape you need:

```
sumOfElements = map (\(_,_,c) -> c) . filter (\(a,b,c) -> a+b==c)
```

And trust that laziness and optimizations (specifically, foldr/build fusion) will make it performant.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this more succinctly with a list comprehension:

```
sumOfElements list = [c | (a,b,c) <- list, a+b==c]
```

Comment: "I want to use the standard prelude (not recursion or list comprehension)"